# Как установить пароль в джумлу?

Tags: joomla, php, пароль

Как добавить пользователя в админку джумлы, если у меня есть доступ только к PHP админке? 
То есть только к БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть SQL и выполнить:

```
INSERT INTO `jos_users` VALUES (
    '', // id auto_increment
    'Administrator', // Группа
    'admin_login', // Логин
    'admin@admin.mail', // Мыло
    '', // md5(пароль)
    'Super Administrator', // Права
    0, // Прочая хрень
    1,
    25,
    '2012-2-2 10:14:19',
    '2012-2-2 12:32:32',
    '',
    '');
```

Перед выполнением убрать //Комменты

Comment: все равно не помогло, а обратное можно узнать? есть админ , как узнать его пароль? если я знаю пароль его в админПХП

Comment: Юнный хацкер чтоли? Жесть... %)

> есть админ , как узнать его пароль?
> если я знаю пароль его в админПХП

Ты хоть понимаешь о чем пишишь? Обрисуй толком задачу!